# Extracting Business Extension from a phone number in Bigquery

Tags: string, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I want to separate phone number into 2 fields in bigquery using regexp expression

1. PhoneNumber
2. Business Extension

The input looks like
[image]

The expected output should look like [image]

Comment: do you have extension for each and every number or some can be without extension?

Comment: Not all the numbers have extensions

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select FullPhoneNumber, 
  regexp_replace(FullPhoneNumber, r'(?i)(.*?)(e?xt?\.?\s*\d+)$', r'\1') as PhoneNumber,
  regexp_extract(FullPhoneNumber, r'(?i)e?xt?\.?\s*(\d+)$') as Extension
from your_table
```

if applied to sample/dummy data

```
with your_table as (
  select "408-697-4639 x. 301" FullPhoneNumber union all 
  select "563-232-1400x6740" union all 
  select "248-456-8250ext. 100" union all 
  select "(123) 456-7890"
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried?

Answer (score -2):

A fixed query. An extension always has the character x.

To replace the brackets the inner Select is needed.

```
with tbl as (
Select "408-697-4639 x. 301" phone
Union ALL Select "563-232-1400x6740"
Union ALL Select "248-456-8250ext. 100"
Union ALL Select " (781) 512-3435")


SELECT *,REGEXP_EXTRACT(phone, r"^[0-9\s\(\)]{0,8}[0-9\-]+") as phoneNumber,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(phone, r"[xX].*\d+$"),r"\d+$") as extension
#FROM 
#(Select regexp_replace(phone,r"\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)\s*", r"\1-")  as phone # Remove brackets
From tbl
#)
```

Comment: REGEXP_EXTRACT(phone, r"\d+$") extension would not work if we dont have extension available; incase the phoneNumber is like (781) 512-3435 ; then the output for extension would be 3435; which is not correct